# I'm searching a Wordpress Plugin for this:

Tags: wordpress, plugins, gallery, slideshow

I'm searching a plugin that let me create a slideshow as similar as possible to this: http://www.cesarevignato.it/gallery/event-photography/

Where can i find it?

Answer (score 0):

This is "carousel", so search for this in the plugin section and you will find many carousel plugins.

Comment: Thanks, i found this, it' great but when i upload rectangular images they doesn't adapt to the other as you can see here: http://www.fotografiadrv.it/prova-slideshow/
Any idea?